# Extract only values with a decimal point in between from strings

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with strings such as:

```
id <- c(1,2)
x <- c("...14.....5.......................395.00.........................14.........1..",
   "......114.99....................124.99................")
df <- data.frame(id,x)
df$x <- as.character(df$x)
```

How can I extract only values with a decimal point in between such as 395.00, 114.99 and 124.99 and not 14, 5, or 1 for each row, and put them in a new column separated by a comma?

The ideal result would be:

```
  id            x2
  1         395.00
  2  114.99,124.99
```

The amount of periods separating the values are random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
df$x2 = str_extract_all(df$x, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")

df[c(1, 3)]
#   id             x2
# 1  1         395.00
# 2  2 114.99, 124.99
```

Explanation: `[0-9]+` matches one or more numbers, `\\.` matches a single decimal point. `str_extract_all` extracts all matches.

The new column is a `list` column, not a string with an inserted comma. This allows you access to the individual elements, if needed:

```
df$x2[2]
# [[1]]
# [1] "114.99" "124.99"
```

If you prefer a character vector as the column, do this:

```
df$x3 = sapply(str_extract_all(df$x, "[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"), paste, collapse = ",")

df$x3[2]
#[1] "114.99,124.99"
```